# Advance to next card object with different elements while using java's cardlayout

Tags: java, swing, applet, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am very new to this site and a novice programmer so I'm hoping someone here can help me with the problem I'm facing. I am making a simple program that uses a card layout to select/enter several user-specific options that will be stored in string variables and then after the last question, used to give a unique answer. Right now the program advances slide's successfully and displays the proper question, however it does not clear the JRadioButton from the first card and keeps using this radio button instead of the desired component for the duration of the program. For example, The second and third card should have JTextField's while the 4th card should have a JComboBox. I have two main class files, one that is the actual frame and the other that is displayed below which does the work behind the scenes. For future reference, I plan to modify this into an applet once it is working properly so any advice on that would be great. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

I believe the problem may stem from the creation of multiple card objects here, the ScreenPanel objects each take the same parameters but depending on the different card, a different Component needs to be produced.

```
        // set up questions
        String question1 = "Sex: ";
        String[] responses1 = {"Female", "Male"};
        ask[0] = new ScreenPanel(question1, responses1);
        String question2 = "Height in inches: ";
        String[] responses2 = new String[1];
        ask[1] = new ScreenPanel(question2, responses2);
        String question3 = "Weight in pounds: ";
        String[] responses3 = new String[1];
        ask[2] = new ScreenPanel(question3, responses3);
        String question4 = "Event: ";
        String[] responses4 = {"Shot Put", "Discus Throw", "Long Jump", "Triple Jump", "High Jump", "Pole Vault", "4 x 800 Relay", "100 Meter Hurdles", "100 Meter Dash", "4 x 200 Relay",
                "1600 Meter Run", "4 x 100 Relay", "400 Meter Dash", "300 Meter Hurdles", "800 Meter Run", "200 Meter Dash", "3200 Meter Run", "4 x 400 Relay"};
        ask[3] = new ScreenPanel(question4, responses4);
        String question5 = "Distance(inches) or Time(seconds)";
        ask[4] = new ScreenPanel(question5, new String[1]);
        ask[4].setFinalQuestion(true);
        addListeners();
    }
```

The Screen Panel class here creates each card, could be a problem with the conditionals but not sure.

```
class ScreenPanel extends JPanel{
    JLabel question;
    JRadioButton[] response1;
    JTextField response2;
    JTextField response3;
    JComboBox response4;
    JTextField response5;
    JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    JButton finalButton = new JButton("Finish");
    String textResponse1, textResponse2, textResponse3, textResponse4, textResponse5;

    ScreenPanel(String ques, String[] resp){
        super();
        setSize(320, 260);
        question = new JLabel(ques);
        JPanel sub1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel sub2 = new JPanel();
        sub1.add(question);
        if (TrackAndField.currentScreen == 0){
            response1 = new JRadioButton[resp.length];
            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            for (int i = 0; i < resp.length; i++){
                response1[i] = new JRadioButton(resp[i], false);
                group.add(response1[i]);
                sub2.add(response1[i]);
            }
//            textResponse1 = group.getSelection().toString();
        }
        if (TrackAndField.currentScreen == 1){
            sub2.remove(response1[0]);
            sub2.remove(response1[1]);
            response2 = new JTextField(4);
            KeyAdapter monitor = new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event){
                    textResponse2 = response2.getText();
                }
            };
            sub2.add(response2);
        }

        if (TrackAndField.currentScreen == 2){
            sub2.remove(response2);
            response3 = new JTextField(10);
            KeyAdapter monitor = new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event){
                    textResponse3 = response3.getText();
                }
            };
            sub2.add(response3);
        }

        if (TrackAndField.currentScreen == 3){
            sub2.remove(response3);
            response4 = new JComboBox(resp);
            sub2.add(response4);
            textResponse4 = response4.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Its not due as an assignment, I'm doing it on my own time. I want people on multiple platforms to be able to use the applet which will be hosted on my website. I am aware that Java Web Start is a viable option so I may look into that more, however default Java runtime settings don't allow self-signed Web Start apps to run so I would have to spend hundreds on a signed certificate for people to use it without changing their settings.

Comment: *"however default Java runtime settings don't allow self-signed Web Start apps to run"*  It's exactly the same case with applets.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I wasn't aware of that, thanks. I'll probably just do it with Web Start in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding an extra string parameter as an ID for the component and used that for the conditionals instead of `currentScreen`